# the definition of interface in this context ( python article )

Tags: python

Quoted from: http://www.toptal.com/python/why-are-there-so-many-pythons

> Surprisingly, that’s a fairly ambiguous statement. What do I mean by ‘Python’? Do I mean Python the abstract interface? Do I mean CPython, the common Python implementation (and not to be confused with the similarly named Cython)?
>
> [...]
>
> The first thing to realize when making a comparison is that ‘Python’ is an interface. There’s a specification of what Python should do and how it should behave (as with any interface). And there are multiple implementations (as with any interface).
>
> The second thing to realize is that ‘interpreted’ and ‘compiled’ are properties of an implementation, not an interface.

Here the word "interface" is not clear at all. Does he mean "standard"? If so why didn't he just write that?

Comment: Looks like there's some text missing at the very beginning of your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They do mean *interface*, the same term as the *I* in the acronym API (*Application Programming Interface*). *Standards* for software define interfaces; or putting it another way, the Python interface is standardised.

From the [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(computing)):

> In computing, an interface is a shared boundary across which two separate components of a computer system exchange information. The exchange can be between software, computer hardware, peripheral devices, humans and combinations of these.

The interface is the surface area that a developer interacts with the Python language and library. By describing that interface, anyone could, in theory, implement their own Python language environment, complete with built-in types and  functions and standard library.

There are also other standards for Python, such as the [Python Enhancement Proposal process](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0001/) and the style guides for [C code written for the CPython project](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0007/) and for [Python code itself](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). These are not interfaces, however.

Comment: interesting do you mean  that interface is the CODE IT SELF   and implementation deals with code ( i m getting that point if not true please explain more thanx ) also if so whats the difference between python and cpython as we know  python uses BY REFERENCE  cpython !

Comment: UP COULD you please explain more

Comment: The interface is a *definition* of what the implementation should do; a specification of what the signatures of callables, the description of how the language should behave, etc. The code itself should conform to the specification.

Comment: the last thing please whats the difference between standard interface and specification

Comment: I don't think there is any.

Answer (score 0):

Interface is here meant in a meaning of definition. The interface Python is a definition of how to use the language to interact with the computer. The implementation (may be CPython or IronPython) does the work based on the interface (code) with the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to think about it:

> Your interface to the Python *implementation* is the standard library
>   that ships with Python.

All downloads of Python available are implementations of the python language on a particular run-time or platform.

The standard, reference implementation, written in the C language is known simply as "Python".

All implementation of Python that conform to the Python standard implementation ship with the Python standard library.

However, an implementer is free to include other tools as part of that particular implementation.

As an example, in Jython (the Python implementation on the Java runtime), you can write the following code:

```
>>> from java.lang import System as javasystem
>>> javasystem.out.println("Hello World")
Hello World
```

This `java.lang` is something that is specific to the Jython implementation of Python. You won't find any documentation for it at the "standard Python" documentation, available at python.org.